# How can I get HTTP headers (Location) from some URL?

Tags: php, http, curl

I have some address (for example: http://example.com/b-out/3456/3212/).This address i must pass through curl. I know that this URL redirects to another URL (like http://sdss.co/go/36a7fe71189fec14c85636f33501f6d2/?...). And this another URL located in the headers (Location) of first URL. How can I get second URL in some variable?

Comment: Disallow curl to automatically follow redirects; let it just make this one request, and parse the returned headers.

Comment: You have to give us a real URL to work with, there are several ways to redirect. And what have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a request to the first URL, confirm a redirect takes place and read the Location header. From [PHP cURL retrieving response headers AND body in a single request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/php-curl-retrieving-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request) and [Check headers in PHP cURL server response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861804/check-headers-in-php-curl-server-response):

```
$curlHandle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$redirectResponse = curl_exec($curlHandle);
```

The options being set there mean: return the response headers, don't return the response body, *don't* automatically follow redirects and return the result in the exec-call.

Now you've got the HTTP response headers, without body, in `$redirectResponse`. You'll now need to verify that it's a redirect:

```
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($curlHandle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($statusCode == 301 || $statusCode == 302 || $statusCode == 303)
{
    $headerLength = curl_getinfo($curlHandle, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $responseHeaders = substr($redirectResponse, 0, $headerLength);
    $redirectUrl = getLocationHeader($responseHeaders);
}
```

Then create a function to do that:

```
function getLocationHeader($responseHeaders)
{

}
```

In there you'll want to `explode()` the `$responseHeaders` on HTTP newline (`\r\n`) and find the header starting with `location`.

---

Alternatively, you can use a more abstract HTTP client library [like `Zend_Http_Client`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350494/getting-response-body-using-zend-http-client), where it is a little easier to obtain the headers.

Comment: "Lovely API"? :-3 Well, it's bare metal, really. Use one of the myriads of abstractions available if you want something nicer... :)

Comment: @Aleksander can you perhaps share how exactly you did it?

Answer (score 0):

I did it like CodeCaster said. This is my function 'getLocationHeader':
    
    `function getLocationHeader($responseHeaders)
    {
        if (preg_match('/Location:(.+)Vary/is', $redirectResponse, $loc))
        {
            $location = trim($loc[1]);
            return $location;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }`